# How can Vue projects be debugged lately?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I'm maintaining a Vue2 project in which I've recently upgraded `@vue/cli-service` to version 5.0.4 (from 4.5.0).
Now I've noticed that I can't use my browser devtools to debug the app anymore. Specifically, when I open the devtools and press `CTRL+P` and type `App.vue`, the browser opens a compiled version of that file. Previously, it would open the original source file and allow me to place working breakpoints in that file.

This problem occurs in Chrome, Edge, and Firefox.

This problem even happens to the default project scaffold generated by the latest `@vue/cli` (version 5.0.4 also), with typescript and babel disabled (eg the project generated using `vue create testProject`).

As a matter of fact, this problem even happens to the default **Vue3/Vite** project scaffold generated by `npm init vue@latest`. With or without typescript. I have no idea how anyone in the Vue ecosystem are debugging their projects anymore.

I've already tried setting `configureWebpack.devtool = 'source-map'` - that hasn't had any effect.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why not using the Vue devtools? https://devtools.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Comment: I am. But Vue devtools - as nice as it is - does not allow you to place breakpoints and step through the code.

Comment: do ```debugger;``` statements work?

Comment: Yes, `debugger;` statements work. But in certain situations they are much less convenient than placing breakpoints. Nobody should have to give up using breakpoints to use Vue.

Comment: @maxshuty I cannot really replicated the buggy behavior stated by OP (my devtools work perfectly) and you can [use this](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#component-debugging-hooks) to debug your code or [this extension](https://github.com/hzmming/vue-force-dev) to be able to inspect a bit more of a production-running app.

Comment: @kissu it's a [real problem](https://github.com/vuejs/core/discussions/9929) that I'm facing and while the extension is nice, it's no replacement for finding out the cause of this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me. I tried to reproduce (npm init vue@latest). When I hit ctrl-p, the first App.vue that's suggested is, as you say, a compiled version. But if you keep hunting down the list, look for the App.vue that has a directory path after it, and you should see your source and be able to put breakpoints. I also like to open my source directory in the filesystem sub-tab of the sources tab in devtools, and this works fine as well, breakpoints included.

[image]

Comment: I'll have to accept this since it answers the title question with "Use vite and manually pick the appropriate version of the target file" . But the `CTRL-P` menu for the vue-cli project doesn't have any working options for (eg) App.vue -- unless, as you suggested, I add the project folder to the filesystem tab. But this can't be done in Firefox. And besides, I thought that's what sourcemaps are for?